# Can Apache HTTP Server be configured to forward a request to multiple backend workers simultaneously?

Tags: apache, http, request, replication

Are you aware of a mod_proxy, mod_proxy_balancer, mod_proxy_http configuration of Apache 2.2 that would allow HTTP requests to be replicated? That is: each matched request is sent to an existing balancer AND replicated to an another worker node.

Goal:
Take production HTTP traffic coming into Apache 2.2, retain normal production load-balanced routing AND replicate that same traffic to one more [test] worker fronting a new back-end database required to be performance and load tested under production operations.

Background info:
Multi-tier system.

```
(a) Custom applications
(b) Redirector/Proxy [Apache 2.2 using mod_proxy, mod_proxy_balancer, mod_proxy_http]
(c) Workers [application server nodes: Tomcat 7.0.56 over Java 1.7.0_67 over 64-bit Linux kernels]
(d) Database [Oracle 11.2]
```

End-users driving custom applications generate HTTP requests funneled to the redirector. The redirector forwards application requests on a round-robin basis to a pool of worker nodes. Workers  directly access backend database. HTTP responses funnel back through the redirector to the end-user workstation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible. But you can save the traffic and replay it with a relatively new module called mod_firehose. But it is not an all in one tool.

Comment: Mille grazie. An itch to scratch for open source: don't see from [Apache 2.2 modules list](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/) that this has been backported. Will chase what our switch capabilities are. Not an operational option to update the aging Apache 2.2 server on an equally aged Solaris cluster, just yet.